# Ubuntu 20.04 lts autoinstall won't work with UEFI over netboot

Tags: 20.04

I am unable to get Ubuntu to recognize my user-data.yml file that is being hosted on my organizations http server, whenever I boot into UEFI mode. I get the default interactive login screen no matter what options I add to the installer command line.
[Ubuntu Welcome Screen but no autoinstall process starting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtlNx.jpg)

However, Legacy/BIOS mode starts and finishes the autoinstall process without any issues. For some reason UEFI mode fails to accept the user-data file.

Does anyone know if there is a working config for UEFI that does not require a PXE boot setup but an autoinsall for UEFI using an http server.

Comment: Out of `isolinux/txt.cfg`, `boot/grub/grub.cfg`, `boot/grub/loopback.cfg`, which of those did you modify? (If any)